# ingress-nginx-controller not working when communicating with istio-ingressgateway in Kubernetes Engine

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, google-kubernetes-engine, istio, nginx-ingress

I have `ingress-nginx-controller` as Load Balancer in my kubernetes cluster, it is working as expected for apps outside of `Istio` service mesh, now I want it to serve some apps inside my service mesh but I keep getting error `502 Bad Gateway`:

[image]

What I want to achieve is

```
[ingress-nginx-controller as LoadBalancer] ===> [Istio's Gateway]===> [my k8s service]
```

I'm following instructions as in these tutorials which use aws alb instead of `ingress-nginx-controller` in front of Istios `gateway`: [tutorial](https://maytan.work/aws-alb-with-istio/) and [another medium tutorial](https://hxhronies.medium.com/how-to-implement-path-based-routing-using-istio-ingress-gateway-on-aws-elastic-kubernetes-service-a15ce34eae3f)

But no success keep getting 502.

This is what my yaml configs look like:

##### My Ingress is:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: istio-ingress
  namespace: istio-ingress
  annotations:
    certmanager.k8s.io/acme-challenge-type: dns01
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/service-upstream: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - "*.example.com"
        - "example.com"
      secretName: wildcard-istio-cert
  rules:
    # Service ingress-nginx-controller will direct traffic to current ingress when hostname requested by client matches the definition in the hosts below
    - host: app.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: istio-ingressgateway # <==== The name of my istio-ingressgateway
                port:
                   number: 443 # (tried returns 502 Bad Gateway & it's as in medium tutorial) 
                  # name: http-web (tried didn't work at all)
                  # name: https-ssl (tried returns 502 Bad Gateway)
                  # number: 30824 #spec.ports.name=="https-ssl" (tried returns 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable)
                  # number: 31849 #spec.ports.name=="http-web" (tried returns 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable)
                  # number: 30276 #spec.ports.name=="status-port" (tried returns 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable)
```

##### This is the istio ingress-gateway `service` of type `NodePort`:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: istio-ingressgateway
  namespace: istio-ingress
  uid: b6d1f4ce-2af4-42f0-be10-9e5d32edc716
  resourceVersion: "58534080"
  creationTimestamp: "2024-02-01T19:39:32Z"
  labels:
    app: istio-ingressgateway
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: istio-ingressgateway
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.20.0
    helm.sh/chart: gateway-1.20.0
    istio: ingressgateway
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress":true}'
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: istio-ingressgateway
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: istio-ingress
spec:
  ports:
  - name: status-port
    protocol: TCP
    port: 15021
    targetPort: 15021
    nodePort: 30276
  - name: http-web
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 31849
  - name: https-ssl
    protocol: TCP
    port: 443
    targetPort: 443
    nodePort: 30824
  selector:
    app: istio-ingressgateway
    istio: ingressgateway
  clusterIP: 34.118.227.128
  clusterIPs:
  - 34.118.227.128
  type: NodePort
  sessionAffinity: None
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

##### And this is the LoadBalancer service `ingress-nginx-controller`:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  resourceVersion: "51046251"
  creationTimestamp: "2024-01-25T22:40:52Z"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.9.0
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-4.8.0
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress":true}'
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: ingress-nginx
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: ingress-nginx
  finalizers:
  - service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: http
    nodePort: 32638
  - name: https
    protocol: TCP
    port: 443
    targetPort: https
    nodePort: 32450
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
  clusterIP: {MY-CLUSTER-IP}
  clusterIPs:
  - 34.118.227.191
  type: LoadBalancer
  sessionAffinity: None
  loadBalancerIP: {MY-IP}
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  healthCheckNodePort: 31936
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  allocateLoadBalancerNodePorts: true
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: {MY-IP}
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing the Gateway resource configuring Istio's ingress gateway + a VirtualService that would route to your desired destination.

Also how do the logs from the Istio ingress gateway pod look like?